# RESTful and SOAP web services

Tags: java, rest, soap

Why RESTful web services are always synchronous while SOAP web services can be implemented as either synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: Nothing stops you from making a rest service async; however you likely need state management in your service.  Some people would say it's not "resty".

Comment: from this https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html
and this https://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2011/06/02/asynchronous-operations-in-rest/ RestFull webservice can be async. read it :)